# net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED after install SSL

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, npm, ssl-certificate

my website was working great, but i need to install certifies SSL.
After install SSL my console show "net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED".

Part of node file.

```
function load() {
query('SET NAMES utf8');
query('sql query was here', function(err, row) {
    if((err) || (!row.length)) {

        process.exit(0);
        return;
    }
    currentid = row[0].id;
});
loadHistory();
setTimeout(function() { io.listen(8080); }, 3000);
}
```

Part of client side script

```
function connect() {
if(!SOCKET) {
    chat("italic", "Generating token...");
    var hash = getCookie('hash');
    if(!hash) {
        chat("italic", "Please, sing through steam.");
    } else {
        chat("italic", "Connecting...");
        SOCKET = io(HOST);
        SOCKET.on('connect', function(msg) {
            chat("italic", "Connected!");
            SOCKET.emit('hash', hash);
        });
        SOCKET.on('connect_error', function(msg) {
            chat("italic", "Conection lost...");
        });
        SOCKET.on('message', function(msg) {
            onMessage(msg);
        });
    }
} else {
    console.log("Error: connection already exists.");
}
```

}